# How to get property from an array of object ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have array of object in json response i want to get `riskAssessmentKey` from `includeAssessmentList` array and pass that key to backend through Post Api,I am not able to get the property from the array. How can i achieve that task ?

So far tried code....

main.js

```
$scope.deleteAssess = function(){
          var assessmentKey = [];
          assessmentKey = $scope.rcsaCycleDTO.includeAssessmentList;
          for (var i=0; i<assessmentKey.length; i++) {
              var riskAssessmentKeys = assessmentKey[i];
              console.log(riskAssessmentKeys);
          }
          RcsaFactory.assessmentDetails(assessmentKey,$scope.rcsaCycleDTO.statusLookUpCode).then(function(){
            setConfirmationWinButtons(true, true, true);
            $scope.confirmationWin.open().center();
            $scope.confirmationWin.close();
          });
        };
```

JSON.js

```
[{includeAssessmentList: 
0: {cycleName: "Test startassment1", assessmentName: "Algeria_Angola", scopeType: null,…}
assessmentEndDate: "06/06/2015"
assessmentName: "Algeria_Angola"
assessmentRoleTypeDTOs: []
assessmentStartDate: "06/05/2015"
assessmentStatus: "Draft"
assessmentStatusLookUpCode: "RA_ASES_DRAFT"
availableRolesKey: []
beginTransactionTime: 1433422729000
createWorkerKey: -1066
createWorkerText: "NBKTHMC"
createdTimestamp: 1433495095000
currentFlag: 1
cycleEndDate: "06/06/2015"
cycleName: "Test startassment1"
cycleStartDate: "06/05/2015"
cycleType: "RA_RCSA"
dueDate: "06/26/2015"
endTransactionTime: 1433495095000
erhFlag: null
erhList: null
filteredErhList: null
geoLocationLst: null
legalEntity: null
modifiedTimestamp: 1433422729000
modifiedTimestampString: "06/04/2015"
modifiedUserText: "NBKTHMC"
modifyWorkerKey: -1066
rcsaOwnerWorkerKey: null
rcsaPreparerWorkerKey: null
responseMesg: null
riskAssessmentCycleKey: null
riskAssessmentKey: 87
riskAssessmentRoleTypeKey: null
scopeType: null
selectedRolesKey: []
sourceFeed: 1
statusLookUpCode: "RS_ACTIVE"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop you are only reading the array item but not the required property `riskAssessmentKey`. Try this.

```
for (var i=0; i<assessmentKey.length; i++) {
   var riskAssessmentKeys = assessmentKey[i].riskAssessmentKey;
   console.log(riskAssessmentKeys);
}
```

If `includeAssessmentList` always contains only one item then you don't need a for loop you can try this.

```
if ($scope.rcsaCycleDTO.includeAssessmentList && $scope.rcsaCycleDTO.includeAssessmentList.length) {
  var riskAssessmentKeys = $scope.rcsaCycleDTO.includeAssessmentList[0].riskAssessmentKey;
}
```

If you have to read all the ristAssetKeyKeys from the array then try this.

```
   var riskAssessmentKeys = [];
   for (var i=0; i<assessmentKey.length; i++) {
      riskAssessmentKeys.push(assessmentKey[i].riskAssessmentKey);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks i will use your first answer option so here once i get the list of riskAssessmentKey i want to send selected key from grid to post service , How can i implement that using first answer...

Comment: For that last code block (getting an array of the `riskAssessmentKey`), while the `for` loop works just fine, the more idiomatic way to do it is via [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `const riskAssessmentKeys = assessmentKey.map(({riskAssessmentKey}) => riskAssessmentKey);`