# How to get item from JSON object when there is only one item?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following `JSON`:

`var x = [{"email":"info@test.nl"}]`

How do I get the email in `javascript`? `x.email` doesn't work for me.

Bart

Comment: Can you show a complete code example of what you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: `x[0].email` should be fine ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get property from an array of object ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670144/how-to-get-property-from-an-array-of-object)

Comment: That's not JSON. That's a JavaScript array initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference to element of the array, then access the property.

```js
var x = [{"email":"info@test.nl"}]
console.log(x[0].email)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the object is inside of an array, you must access the correct array element first, so use: `x[0].email`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read the JSON inside an array, `use x[0].email`.

Comment: Array literal notation is part of JSON.

Comment: @Pointy I meant that `var x = [{"email":"info@test.nl"}]` is not JSON, but an array containing the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON first:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(x);
var entry = arr[0].email;
```

Comment: No, in the code the OP posted it's not JSON in the first place; it's a JavaScript array initializer. No parsing is necessary.

Comment: Oh. My bad. I thought it was a string. Guess I didn't look close enough.